# how to get longest width as width of all $('li') with jquery

Tags: jquery, width

```
<ul>
  <li>Short</li>
   <li>Short</li>
   <li>Short
    <ul>
       <li>Short</li>
       <li>Longer</li>
       <li>This is the longest (how do i get this longest width as width of all LI siblings with in this UL only)</li>
   <ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why not just set the maximum width using css?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `offsetWidth` propriety.

`function getMaxLiWidth(){
  var maxWidth = 0;
  $('li').each(function(i){
    if(this.offsetWidth > maxWidth)
      maxWidth = this.offsetWidth;
  });
  return maxWidth;
}`

If you want to return the 'li'element with the longest width, you should probably save the 'i' indice in the function and then you could select it such as: `$('li:nth-child('+i+')')`.
The function would then be : 

`function getMaxLiWidth(){
  var maxWidth = 0,index=0;
  $('li').each(function(i){
    if(this.offsetWidth > maxWidth)
      {
        maxWidth = this.offsetWidth;
        index = i;
      }
  });
  return $('li:nth-child('+index+')');
}`

Answer (score 0):

The ul should wrap around the li's and become the width of the widest li, so looking at the width of the ul should do the trick, unless the ul is display: block and non-floatet

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this, because `li` elements are block level.  This means that they automatically take up the entire width of the parent element.  [See this jsFiddle to show this](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/SGvbW/).

Answer (score 0):

The width of the li-tag depends on the ul-width, so if you have the ul display:block the li-width will return the width of the ul (100%);

BUT you can get the the width of a inline-element inside a li-tag.
if you don't have a inline-element inside the li :-)

```
var maxWidth = 0;
//total amount of li-tags
var maxli = $('ul li').length-1;

$('ul li').each(
    function(index){
            //wrap li-content width inline element like <span>
        $(this).wrapInner( "<span></span>");

            //get max-width of spans
        if( $(this).children('span').width() > maxWidth ){
            maxWidth = $(this).children('span').width();
        }

        //complete
        if(index == maxli){
                    //set width of parent ul-tag to max-size of the longest li-tag
            $(this).parent('ul').width(maxWidth);
        }   
    }
);
```